# S3 Bucket Policy for Hosted Static Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket that is being used to host a static website. [This example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html) shows a policy that grants *everyone* access to the objects in the specified bucket (i.e. making the website public):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
     "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Principal": "*",
     "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
     "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"]
  }]
}
```

However, I want to make the website accessible to only specific Amazon users. So following [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html), I specify these users in `Principal`:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
     "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-ID:user/Dave"
     },
     "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
     "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"]
  }]
}
```

While this correctly enables permissions for who can access the resource via the S3 console, it results in a 403 for *everybody* trying to access the hosted website.

*Is it possible to have user-level permissions restricting access to a hosted bucket?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to apply user-level permissions to a static web site bucket in S3.  From [Permissions Required for Website Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html):

> When you configure a bucket as a website, you must make the objects that you want to serve publicly readable.